# Difference between HandleEvent of Listener Interface versus Specific <Selection/Key/Focus>Event of <Selection/Key/Focus>Listener Interface

Tags: java, eclipse, event-handling, swt, listener

Please help me understand the difference between `handleEvent` of `Listener` interface versus `<Selection/Key/Focus>Event` of `<Selection/Key/Focus>Listener` interfaces . Thanks in Advance.

I have come across `handleEvent` method with `Event` parameter where the usage is `SWT.FocusIn` or `SWT.FocusOut` for `Listener` Interface. And then there is also `focusGained`/`focusLost` `FocusEvent` parameter.

Similarly it is the same with `SWT.Selection` used in `handleEvent` method and then there is also `keyPressed`/`keyReleased` `KeyEvent` of `KeyListener` Interface.

Similarly it is the same with `SWT.KeyDown` or `SWT.KeyUp` used in `handleEvent` method and then there is also  `widgetSelected`/`widgetDefaultSelected` `SelectionEvent` of `SelectionListener` Interface.

These appear to me as same/duplicate. Is there any difference or reason why we should use one versus other?

Comment: Did my answer solve you question? If so, please accept it. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you discovered there are *typed* and *untyped* events.

As you already found out, there is a connection. The typed events are the ones that look like this:

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
});
```

Whereas the untyped events look like this:

```
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {}
});
```

---

If you look at the source of `Button`, you will see this:

```
public void addSelectionListener (SelectionListener listener) {
    checkWidget();
    if (listener == null) error(SWT.ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT);
    TypedListener typedListener = new TypedListener(listener);
    addListener(SWT.Selection, typedListener);
    addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, typedListener);
}
```

As you can see, `addSelectionListener` just calls `addListener`.

---

Concluding: It is kind of redundant, but it makes the source more usable. If you want to take care of all the cases that have to do with selection, add the `SelectionListener`. If you just want to take care of `SWT.Selection`, aadd the `Listener`.

It really is a matter of taste. I prefer to add the untyped event listeners, because I find myself often not using all the methods of a `SelectionListener` or a `MouseListener` when I only want to take care of one event.

---

Finally: [Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354574&seqNum=3) is something to read if you want to know more (and have a mapping between typed and untyped events).

Especially this part:

> In early versions of SWT, there were only untyped listeners. After considerable discussion between the Eclipse implementers, the SWT user community, and the developers, it was decided to include a more "JavaBeans-like" listener mechanism. It was felt that this would ease the transition to SWT for developers who were already familiar with AWT/Swing. The untyped listeners remain as the implementation mechanism for event handling in SWT. The typed listeners are defined in terms of them.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. I have an additional clarifications, I noticed that we could implement the <Selection/Key/Focus>Listener to each individual widget or it could be implemented by the WizardPagesSubClass and have one implementation of widgetSelected & widgetDefaultSelected for all the three widgets. Any reason why we should be choosing one approach versus other? Is it just to avoid repetitions of the same functionality across similar widgets? or is there any other reason as well? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @rkanth Depends on if the WizardPagesSubClass actually fires <Selection/Key/Focus>Events. I personally prefer to attach the `Listener`s to the individual entities. If they all do the same, I use the same `Listener` instance.

Comment: Thank you! to clarify, "If they all do the same, I use the same Listener instance." --For this I should be creating MyCustomListener extending the <Selection/Key/Focus>Listener interfaces to implement common functionality and then use that instance. Is that right or is it something else? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @rkanth You should create an instance of that Listener, i.e. either a new class implementing it or an anonymous class.